# Controller action hanging for few seconds after SQL request execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm facing a problem I can't figure out. I've got an action in an ASP .NET Core controller that seems to hang for quite some time after an SQL request being executed.

Here is the code sample:

```cs
[HttpGet("slow/action/{scopeType}/{scopeId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MySlowAction(ScopeType scopeType, Guid scopeId)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<SalesOrder> orders = this.DbContext.SalesOrders
            .Include(so => so.Store)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.District)
            .Include(so => so.OrderingPlatform)
            .Include(so => so.Items)
                .ThenInclude(soi => soi.Items);
        switch (scopeType)
        {
            case ScopeType.Region:
                Region region = await this.DbContext.Regions
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == scopeId);
                if (region == null)
                {
                    this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(scopeId), $"Failed to find a region with the specified id '{scopeId}'");
                    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
                }
                orders = orders.Where(so => so.Store.District.RegionId == region.Id);
                break;
            default:
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(scopeType), $"The specified scope type '{scopeType}' is not supported");
                return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
        orders = orders
            .Where(so =>
                so.State == SalesOrderState.Prepared || so.State == SalesOrderState.Completed
                && so.Destination == SalesOrderDestination.Customer
                && so.DueDate.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date
            )
            .ToList();
        ScopeStatisticsInfo stats = new ScopeStatisticsInfo()
        {
            ScopeType = scopeType,
            ScopedId = scopeId,
            TotalTickets = orders.Count(),
            TotalSales = orders.SelectMany(so => so.Items).Sum(soi => soi.Quantity),
            TotalSalesTurnover = orders.Sum(so => so.Total),
            AverageTicket = orders.Any() ? orders.Average(so => so.Total) : (decimal?)null,
            AverageSalesPerTicket = orders.Any() ? orders.Average(so => so.Items.Sum(soi => soi.Quantity)) : (double?)null,
            TopSales = orders
                .SelectMany(so => so.Items)
                .GroupBy(so => so.ProductId)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(soi => soi.Quantity))
                .Take(3)
                .Select(g => new ProductSalesInfo()
                {
                    Product = this.Mapper.Map<ProductInfo>(this.DbContext.Products.First(p => p.Id == g.First().ProductId)),
                    Sales = g.Sum(soi => soi.Quantity)
                })
                .ToList()
        };
        return this.Ok(stats);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        this.Logger?.LogError($"An error occured while retrieving the statistics of the scope of type '{scopeType}', with id '{scopeId}':{Environment.NewLine}{ex.ToString()}");
        return this.StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

In my use-case, the action seems to hang between the call to the .ToList() method and the instanciation of the new ScopeStatisticsInfo.

The underlying SQL request from the .ToList() method takes only 800ms to execute and, in my test case, returns no entities, the list is empty. But still, the process will hang for few seconds, with some unknown threads exiting, before hitting the "new ScopeStatisticsInfo". The overall action takes about 30/40seconds. Here is a debug output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://foo.bar.com/api/v1/dashboard/slow/action/region/ceffa31f-ce09-4ed8-8717-1dbc73d968b7?ui-culture=fr  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 20.8107ms 204 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://foo.bar.com/api/v1/dashboard/slow/action/region/ceffa31f-ce09-4ed8-8717-1dbc73d968b7?ui-culture=fr  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {area = "api", action = "MySlowAction", controller = "Dashboard"}. Executing action Foo.Bar.Controllers.DashboardController.MySlowAction (Foo.Bar)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization was successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method Foo.Bar.Controllers.DashboardController.MySlowAction (Foo.Bar) with arguments (Region, ceffa31f-ce09-4ed8-8717-1dbc73d968b7) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure:Information: Entity Framework Core 2.2.2-servicing-10034 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__scopeId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [r].[Id], [r].[CreatedAt], [r].[Currency], [r].[DescriptionKey], [r].[IsDeleted], [r].[IsoCode], [r].[Label], [r].[LastModified], [r].[NameKey], [r].[RowVersion]
FROM [Regions] AS [r]
WHERE ([r].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([r].[Id] = @__scopeId_0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__scopeId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [r].[Id], [r].[CreatedAt], [r].[Currency], [r].[DescriptionKey], [r].[IsDeleted], [r].[IsoCode], [r].[Label], [r].[LastModified], [r].[NameKey], [r].[RowVersion]
FROM [Regions] AS [r]
WHERE ([r].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([r].[Id] = @__scopeId_0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (243ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [so].[Id], [so].[Alias], [so].[Comments], [so].[ContactPhoneNumberId], [so].[ContactPhoneNumberSnapshot], [so].[CreatedAt], [so].[Currency], [so].[CustomerEmailSnapshot], [so].[CustomerId], [so].[DeliveryAddressId], [so].[DeliveryAddressSnapshot], [so].[Destination], [so].[Dispatcher], [so].[DueDate], [so].[InvoiceAddressId], [so].[InvoiceAddressSnapshot], [so].[LastModified], [so].[OrderTypeId], [so].[OrderingPlatformId], [so].[PreparationTime], [so].[PreparedAt], [so].[RowVersion], [so].[Sequence], [so].[State], [so].[StoreId], [so].[SubTotal], [so].[TimeSlotId], [so].[Total], [so].[TotalDiscounts], [so].[TotalFees], [so].[TotalImplicitDiscounts], [so].[TotalTaxes], [so.OrderingPlatform].[Id], [so.OrderingPlatform].[CreatedAt], [so.OrderingPlatform].[DescriptionKey], [so.OrderingPlatform].[Label], [so.OrderingPlatform].[LastModified], [so.OrderingPlatform].[NameKey], [so.OrderingPlatform].[OrderChannelType], [so.OrderingPlatform].[RowVersion], [so.OrderingPlatform].[Spi], [t].[Id], [t].[AddressId], [t].[CreatedAt], [t].[DeliveryProvider], [t].[DescriptionKey], [t].[DistrictId], [t].[Email], [t].[IsDeleted], [t].[Label], [t].[LastModified], [t].[MaximumDeliveryDistance], [t].[MaximumOrderLifetime], [t].[MaximumStackableDeliveries], [t].[MaximumStackableDeliveryDistance], [t].[MaximumStackingInterval], [t].[NameKey], [t].[RowVersion], [t].[SalesOrderDispatcher], [t].[StockId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[CreatedAt], [t0].[DescriptionKey], [t0].[IsDeleted], [t0].[Label], [t0].[LastModified], [t0].[NameKey], [t0].[RegionId], [t0].[RowVersion], [t0].[TimeZoneId]
FROM [SalesOrders] AS [so]
INNER JOIN [Applications] AS [so.OrderingPlatform] ON [so].[OrderingPlatformId] = [so.OrderingPlatform].[Id]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[AddressId], [s].[CreatedAt], [s].[DeliveryProvider], [s].[DescriptionKey], [s].[DistrictId], [s].[Email], [s].[IsDeleted], [s].[Label], [s].[LastModified], [s].[MaximumDeliveryDistance], [s].[MaximumOrderLifetime], [s].[MaximumStackableDeliveries], [s].[MaximumStackableDeliveryDistance], [s].[MaximumStackingInterval], [s].[NameKey], [s].[RowVersion], [s].[SalesOrderDispatcher], [s].[StockId]
    FROM [Stores] AS [s]
    WHERE [s].[IsDeleted] = 0
) AS [t] ON [so].[StoreId] = [t].[Id]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[CreatedAt], [d].[DescriptionKey], [d].[IsDeleted], [d].[Label], [d].[LastModified], [d].[NameKey], [d].[RegionId], [d].[RowVersion], [d].[TimeZoneId]
    FROM [Districts] AS [d]
    WHERE [d].[IsDeleted] = 0
) AS [t0] ON [t].[DistrictId] = [t0].[Id]
ORDER BY [so].[Id]
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (183ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [so.Items].[Id], [so.Items].[Comments], [so.Items].[CompositionItemType], [so.Items].[CreatedAt], [so.Items].[DisplayOrder], [so.Items].[ImplicitDiscount], [so.Items].[IsCustomized], [so.Items].[LastModified], [so.Items].[OrderId], [so.Items].[ParentOrderItemId], [so.Items].[ProductId], [so.Items].[ProductLabel], [so.Items].[ProductPrice], [so.Items].[ProductPriceSpecificationId], [so.Items].[Quantity], [so.Items].[RowVersion], [so.Items].[SubTotal], [so.Items].[Total], [so.Items].[TotalDiscounts], [so.Items].[TotalFees], [so.Items].[TotalTaxes], [so.Items].[VatId], [so.Items].[VatLabel], [so.Items].[VatRate]
FROM [SalesOrderItems] AS [so.Items]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [so0].[Id]
    FROM [SalesOrders] AS [so0]
    INNER JOIN [Applications] AS [so.OrderingPlatform0] ON [so0].[OrderingPlatformId] = [so.OrderingPlatform0].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [s0].*
        FROM [Stores] AS [s0]
        WHERE [s0].[IsDeleted] = 0
    ) AS [t1] ON [so0].[StoreId] = [t1].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [d0].*
        FROM [Districts] AS [d0]
        WHERE [d0].[IsDeleted] = 0
    ) AS [t2] ON [t1].[DistrictId] = [t2].[Id]
) AS [t3] ON [so.Items].[OrderId] = [t3].[Id]
ORDER BY [t3].[Id], [so.Items].[Id]
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (837ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [so.Items.Items].[Id], [so.Items.Items].[Comments], [so.Items.Items].[CompositionItemType], [so.Items.Items].[CreatedAt], [so.Items.Items].[DisplayOrder], [so.Items.Items].[ImplicitDiscount], [so.Items.Items].[IsCustomized], [so.Items.Items].[LastModified], [so.Items.Items].[OrderId], [so.Items.Items].[ParentOrderItemId], [so.Items.Items].[ProductId], [so.Items.Items].[ProductLabel], [so.Items.Items].[ProductPrice], [so.Items.Items].[ProductPriceSpecificationId], [so.Items.Items].[Quantity], [so.Items.Items].[RowVersion], [so.Items.Items].[SubTotal], [so.Items.Items].[Total], [so.Items.Items].[TotalDiscounts], [so.Items.Items].[TotalFees], [so.Items.Items].[TotalTaxes], [so.Items.Items].[VatId], [so.Items.Items].[VatLabel], [so.Items.Items].[VatRate]
FROM [SalesOrderItems] AS [so.Items.Items]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [so.Items0].[Id], [t6].[Id] AS [Id0]
    FROM [SalesOrderItems] AS [so.Items0]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT [so1].[Id]
        FROM [SalesOrders] AS [so1]
        INNER JOIN [Applications] AS [so.OrderingPlatform1] ON [so1].[OrderingPlatformId] = [so.OrderingPlatform1].[Id]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [s1].*
            FROM [Stores] AS [s1]
            WHERE [s1].[IsDeleted] = 0
        ) AS [t4] ON [so1].[StoreId] = [t4].[Id]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [d1].*
            FROM [Districts] AS [d1]
            WHERE [d1].[IsDeleted] = 0
        ) AS [t5] ON [t4].[DistrictId] = [t5].[Id]
    ) AS [t6] ON [so.Items0].[OrderId] = [t6].[Id]
) AS [t7] ON [so.Items.Items].[ParentOrderItemId] = [t7].[Id]
ORDER BY [t7].[Id0], [t7].[Id]
Le thread 0x2f7c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0x31a0 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0x2b4c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0x128 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0x333c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0x2ba0 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0x119c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[CreatedAt], [s].[DescriptionKey], [s].[Label], [s].[LastModified], [s].[NameKey], [s].[RowVersion]
FROM [SalesOrderTypes] AS [s]
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__sourceMember_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [ls].[Id], [ls].[CreatedAt], [ls].[Key], [ls].[Language], [ls].[LastModified], [ls].[RowVersion], [ls].[Value]
FROM [LocalizedStrings] AS [ls]
WHERE [ls].[Key] = @__sourceMember_0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method Foo.Bar.Controllers.DashboardController.MySlowAction (Foo.Bar), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 36945.1908ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor:Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Foo.Bar.Controllers.ScopeStatisticsInfo'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action Foo.Bar.Controllers.DashboardController.MySlowAction (Foo.Bar) in 36960.649ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 36975.0473ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Note that when the SalesOrder table is empty, this behavior doesn't happen but when the table is populates with quite a lot of entries, even if the result of the request has no entities, it will hang for quite some time "in between" the two lines of code mentioned earlier.

I'm totally clueless on what is happening, does anybody knows why would the action hang like this even if it's not materializing any entities before continuing?

Comment: You have a pretty complex query... that might be taking good amount of time to execute on database.... did you try running this query directly against the database from SQL Management Studio? Does it take the same amount of time there too? You might want to look at how to simplify the query and execute multiple simple queries instead of one complex query with lot of JOINs.

Comment: As @ChetanRanpariya mentioned, the queries look over complex, even by selecting only the columns that you need you can increase performance, I would first simplify my queries as suggested and then from there I would only select the columns actually needed.

Comment: To be honnest, I didn't execute the query directly but it's stated that it takes ~800ms to execute "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (837ms)". Am I missing something?

Comment: "The underlying SQL request from the .ToList() method takes only 800ms" Only 800ms!!! that is quite slow IMHO, you may want to look into optimize that query, look at the execution plan, add some indexes etc...

Comment: @Isma if you compare the 800ms against the 30/40sec the whole action takes, it can be qualified as "only" :)

Comment: What happens if you don't call ToList in your first query? i.e. orders

Comment: It's even worse, each time "orders" is used in the code that follow, the query is executed... Btw, after thinking about it, I don't understand why there is no "WHERE" clause in the queries displayed in the output...

Comment: Maybe not your highest priority issue. But 800ms for an sql query sounds wrong for me. Maybe your're getting too much rows and copying the data (into your domain objects) takes that much time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but I found a solution. Splitting the operations on "orders" into 2 sequences, one using a IQueryable and the second just to gather the list, really improved to process:

```cs
IQueryable<SalesOrder> ordersQuery = this.DbContext.SalesOrders
    .Include(so => so.Store)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.District)
    .Include(so => so.OrderingPlatform)
    .Include(so => so.Items)
        .ThenInclude(soi => soi.Items);
switch (scopeType)
{
    case ScopeType.Region:
        Region region = await this.DbContext.Regions
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == scopeId);
        if (region == null)
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(scopeId), $"Failed to find a region with the specified id '{scopeId}'");
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
        ordersQuery = ordersQuery.Where(so => so.Store.District.RegionId == region.Id);
        break;
    default:
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(scopeType), $"The specified scope type '{scopeType}' is not supported");
        return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
}
ordersQuery = ordersQuery
    .Where(so =>
        so.State == SalesOrderState.Prepared || so.State == SalesOrderState.Completed
        && so.Destination == SalesOrderDestination.Customer
        && so.DueDate.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date
    );
List<SalesOrder> orders = await ordersQuery.ToListAsync();
```

For the same use-case, the action takes few milliseconds instead of the 30/40seconds:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action Foo.Bar.Controllers.DashboardController.MySlowAction (Foo.Bar) in 269.9177ms
```